# Xamarin iOS Firebase FCM cant connect

Tags: firebase, xamarin, xamarin.ios, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a problem with Firebase FCM implementation in my Xamarin iOS app.

My app delegate looks like this:

```
// The UIApplicationDelegate for the application. This class is responsible for launching the 
// User Interface of the application, as well as listening (and optionally responding) to 
// application events from iOS.
[Register("AppDelegate")]
public class AppDelegate : MvxApplicationDelegate, IUNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
{

    // class-level declarations
    public override bool WillFinishLaunching(UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
    {
        //base.WillFinishLaunching(application, launchOptions);
        Window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
        var launchScreen = (LaunchScreen)_launchStoryboard.InstantiateViewController("LaunchScreen");
        Window.RootViewController = launchScreen;
        this.SetWindow(Window);
        Window.MakeKeyAndVisible();

        return true;
    }


    public override UIWindow Window { get; set; }

    //
    // This method is invoked when the application is about to move from active to inactive state.
    //
    // OpenGL applications should use this method to pause.
    //
    public override void OnResignActivation(UIApplication application)
    {
    }

    // This method should be used to release shared resources and it should store the application state.
    // If your application supports background exection this method is called instead of WillTerminate
    // when the user quits.
    public override void DidEnterBackground(UIApplication application)
    {
        var offline = Mvx.Resolve<IOfflineContent>();
        offline.StopGpsWatcher();

        Messaging.SharedInstance.Disconnect();
    }

    // This method is called as part of the transiton from background to active state.
    public override void WillEnterForeground(UIApplication application)
    {
        var offline = Mvx.Resolve<IOfflineContent>();
        offline.StartGpsWatcher();
    }

    // This method is called when the application is about to terminate. Save data, if needed. 
    public override void WillTerminate(UIApplication application)
    {
    }

    private static UIStoryboard _launchStoryboard = UIStoryboard.FromName("Launch", null);

    public override void FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application)
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += ExceptionHandler.CurrentDomainOnUnhandledException;
        TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += ExceptionHandler.TaskSchedulerOnUnobservedTaskException;

        var presenter = new MvxTouchViewPresenter(this, Window);
        var setup = new Setup(this, presenter);
        setup.Initialize();

        var startup = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxAppStart>();
        startup.Start();

        RegisterForNotificationFcm();
    }

    private void RegisterForNotificationFcm()
    {
        // get permission for notification
        if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(10, 0))
        {
            // iOS 10
            var authOptions = UNAuthorizationOptions.Alert | UNAuthorizationOptions.Badge | UNAuthorizationOptions.Sound;
            UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.RequestAuthorization(authOptions, (granted, error) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(granted);
            });

            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.Delegate = this;
        }
        else
        {
            // iOS 9 <=
            var allNotificationTypes = UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound;
            var settings = UIUserNotificationSettings.GetSettingsForTypes(allNotificationTypes, null);
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterUserNotificationSettings(settings);
        }

        UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotifications();

        //ConnectFcm();

        Firebase.InstanceID.InstanceId.Notifications.ObserveTokenRefresh((sender, e) =>
        {
            var newToken = Firebase.InstanceID.InstanceId.SharedInstance.Token;
            // if you want to send notification per user, use this token
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(newToken);

            ConnectFcm();
        });
    }

    public override void OnActivated(UIApplication uiApplication)
    {
        base.OnActivated(uiApplication);
    }

    public override void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSData deviceToken)
    {
        Messaging.SharedInstance.ApnsToken = deviceToken;
        ConnectFcm();
    }

    // iOS 9 <=, fire when recieve notification foreground
    public override void DidReceiveRemoteNotification(UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo, Action<UIBackgroundFetchResult> completionHandler)
    {
        Messaging.SharedInstance.AppDidReceiveMessage(userInfo);

        // Generate custom event
        NSString[] keys = { new NSString("Event_type") };
        NSObject[] values = { new NSString("Recieve_Notification") };
        var parameters = NSDictionary<NSString, NSObject>.FromObjectsAndKeys(keys, values, keys.Length);

        // Send custom event
        Firebase.Analytics.Analytics.LogEvent("CustomEvent", parameters);

        if (application.ApplicationState == UIApplicationState.Active)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(userInfo);
            var aps_d = userInfo["aps"] as NSDictionary;
            var alert_d = aps_d["alert"] as NSDictionary;
            var body = alert_d["body"] as NSString;
            var title = alert_d["title"] as NSString;
            DebugAlert(title, body);
        }
    }

    // iOS 10, fire when recieve notification foreground
    [Export("userNotificationCenter:willPresentNotification:withCompletionHandler:")]
    public void WillPresentNotification(UNUserNotificationCenter center, UNNotification notification, Action<UNNotificationPresentationOptions> completionHandler)
    {
        var title = notification.Request.Content.Title;
        var body = notification.Request.Content.Body;
        DebugAlert(title, body);
    }

    private void ConnectFcm()
    {
        try
        {
            Firebase.Core.App.Configure();

            Messaging.SharedInstance.Connect((error) =>
            {
                if (error == null)
                {
                    //Messaging.SharedInstance.Subscribe("/topics/all");
                }

                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(error != null ? "error occured" : "connect success");
            });
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }

    private void DebugAlert(string title, string message)
    {
        var alert = new UIAlertView(title ?? "Title", message ?? "Message", null, "Cancel", "OK");
        alert.Show();
    }
}
```

I have error in ConnectFCM method "{The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.fcm error 501.)}"

I test it on simulator I think on simulator it doesnt work (I mean recieve notification) but connect works or not? I tried it too on real device but same app crash from start....

Comment: You need a real device to test FCM. You will need to debug and resolve your crash issue and test the FCM on a real device

Comment: I have same error on real device

Comment: I ConnectFcm method same error and in Main try catch block I have "Foundation.You_Should_Not_Call_base_In_This_Method: Exception of type 'Foundation.You_Should_Not_Call_base_In_This_Method' was thrown."

Comment: don't call `base` the place where you get the exception...

Comment: which base you mean now?

Comment: @Cheesebaron ye I got it u mean in OnActivated method

Answer (score 0):

You should enable the firebase domain in `info.plist`.

```
<key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
<dict>
    <key>firebaseio.com</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</dict>
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>remote-notification</string>
</array>
```

Refer to [Xamarin Firebase for iOS giving fcm 501 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47759301/xamarin-firebase-for-ios-giving-fcm-501-error)